# Rollback database changes using implicit savepoints? - Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Can I rollback changes to the database using implicit savepoints? I ended up making changes(`INSERTs`) through my Java code that I would want to revert back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a SAVEPOINT as outlined at [How to COMMIT, ROLLBACK  Oracle Transactions](http://www.oracle-dba-online.com/sql/commit_rollback_savepoint.htm).

Here's the SAVEPOINT snippet from it...

```
SAVEPOINT

Specify a point in a transaction to which later you can roll back.

Example

insert into emp (empno,ename,sal) values (109,’Sami’,3000);
savepoint a;
insert into dept values (10,’Sales’,’Hyd’);
savepoint b;
insert into salgrade values (‘III’,9000,12000);

Now if you give

rollback to a;

Then  row from salgrade table and dept will be roll backed. Now you can commit the row inserted into emp table or rollback the transaction.

If you give

rollback to b;

Then row inserted into salgrade table will be roll backed. Now you can commit the row inserted into dept table and emp table or rollback to savepoint a or completely roll backed the transaction.

If you give

rollback;

Then the whole transactions is roll backed.

If you give

commit;

Then the whole transaction is committed and all savepoints are removed.
```

Comment: the changes have already been made and I did not use any savepoint !! Hence my question if I can use them having made changes through Java code.

Comment: @darkie15 - if the Java block that ran the inserts has completed then there's no memory object still holding the variables and therefore no way to get ahold of them.  So, what's been done is done in your Java app as the objects that did the inserting are probably gone by now...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Using Oracle Flashback Technology](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28424/adfns_flashback.htm). Assuming your database is already set up for it then you can flashback to a time before the inserts. Though be careful if other users are also updating this table. Also, it's ony recommended if you've made a mistake and will manually flash it back, I wouldn't build this in to any code to automatically do so.