# oracle : Rollback changes done according to specified date (e.g. today)

Tags: oracle

I am developing a code to dump excel sheet into oracle database. I have to perform several validations. Is there a way to rollback changes done by my applications today in oracle.

I need it so that i can test my applications for various scenarios . !

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318794/rollback-database-changes-using-implicit-savepoints-oracle

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c17trans.htm

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25518/adfns_flashback.htm